# Socket abilities

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I am making a board game for some users. I am learning how to send and receive messages from a socket server.

```vb
Private Sub doChat()
    Dim requestCount As Integer
    Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
    Dim dataFromClient As String
    Dim sendBytes As [Byte]()
    Dim serverResponse As String
    Dim rCount As String
    requestCount = 0

    While (True)
        Try
            requestCount = requestCount + 1
            Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = _
            clientSocket.GetStream()
            networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length)
            dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)
            dataFromClient = _
                dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))
            msg("From client-" + clNo + dataFromClient)
            rCount = Convert.ToString(requestCount)

            serverResponse = "Server to clinet(" + clNo + ") " + dataFromClient
            sendBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(serverResponse)
            networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length)
            networkStream.Flush()
            msg(serverResponse)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try

    End While

End Sub
```

My question is, what else can I send or receive by sockets? Can I send events? Functions? Elements? Structures? What is the method? I didn't find any article or video clip about this.

Comment: You can only send and receive `Bytes`. It is completely up to you what those `Bytes` represent. You can't send an event, but you can send a sequence of `Bytes` that indicates that something happened and what it was. You can serialise an object and send that. You convert whatever you have to `Bytes` in whatever manner is appropriate and convert it back again at the other end.

Comment: Some languages let you send things over sockets. Serialization is indeed a good word to look up. It lets you convert objects to bytes.